# .NET version of TNonblockingServer

Tags: c#, .net, thrift

Is there any known .NET versions of async servers and protocols for Thrift? Especially I'm looking for  TThreadedSelectorServer version written in C#.

I just checked out the git repository, but the CSharp version is missing a lot of stuff in comparison with Java version.

Answer (score 0):

There is an RPC framework that uses the standard thrift Protocol named "thrifty", and it is the same effect as using thrift IDL to define the service, that is, thrify can be compatible with code that uses thrift IDL, which is very helpful for cross-platform and it uses DotNetty (windows is iocp, linux is nio)

```
[ThriftStruct]
public class LogEntry
{

    [ThriftConstructor]
    public LogEntry([ThriftField(1)]String category, [ThriftField(2)]String message)
    {
        this.Category = category;
        this.Message = message;
    }

    [ThriftField(1)]
    public String Category { get; }

    [ThriftField(2)]
    public String Message { get; }
}

[ThriftService("scribe")]
public interface IScribe
{
    [ThriftMethod("getMessages")]
    List<LogEntry> GetMessages();

    [ThriftMethod]
    ResultCode Log(List<LogEntry> messages);
}

public class Scribe : IScribe
{
    public List<LogEntry> GetMessages()
    {
        return new List<LogEntry>
        {
            new LogEntry { Category = "c1", Message = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() },
            new LogEntry { Category = "c2", Message = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() },
            new LogEntry { Category = "c3", Message = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() }
        };
    }

    public ResultCode Log(List<LogEntry> messages)
    {
        return ResultCode.TRY_LATER;
    }
}
```

C#: https://github.com/endink/Thrifty
Similar Java can use Swift: https://github.com/facebook/swift